# How to fix "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" error in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, logging

I'm upgrading a python 2.7 code to python 3.6, but every time I'm trying to write something on console using logging I get this error

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I've read most of the similiar questions with this but none of them has worked.

```py
# mainTest.py module
from config import logger
log = logger.getLogger(__file__)

def function():
    message = "testing"
    log.info(message)
    # code
```

```py
# logger.py
import logging
import os
import classpathDir as cf


def getLogger(loggerForFile):
    logger = logging.getLogger(os.path.basename(loggerForFile))
    if not logger.handlers:
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                            datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', filename=cf.ROOT_DIR + "/output/processing.log",
                            filemode='wb', level=logging.DEBUG)
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # set a format which is simpler for console use
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                                      datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S')
        # tell the handler to use this format
        console.setFormatter(formatter)
        # add the handler to the root logger
        logger.addHandler(console)
    return logger


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Logging config module")
```

When I was using this very same code on python2.7 i got this output:

```py
22/05/2019 01:38:11 mainTest.py   : INFO     testing
```

On python 3.6 with the same code I got this error:

```py
22/05/2019 03:17:59 mainRF.py   : INFO     testing
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 996, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Call stack:
  File "mainTest.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_combinations()
  File "mainTest.py", line 20, in run_combinations
    log.info(message)
Message: 'testing'
Arguments: ()
```

Comment: Your code just executes fine on my setup.. Python 3.7.3 x64..

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: Done. Added the full stack trace

Comment: I'm guessing that the placeholder "some code to set a format which is simpler for console use" is installing a formatter that is not returning the correct type.

Comment: Just updated the question with the missing code

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and post the stack trace from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting logging basic config I changed 
`python filemode='wb'` to 
`python filemode='w'` and it worked properly.